# flex 3d charting component with 3 axis (x,y,z)

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I have done a lot of research trying to find a free flex 3d charting component that can render column charts over 3 axes, but i couldn't find any. Does anyone know any ?

I'm trying to render charts like this :

[image: This is a chart with 3 axes, each representing a factor, rendered in excel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to search some 3D game engines (for example, Alternative), but I guess, it will be much easyer to handle it dwawing charts in 2D, in perspective: it is realy simple to draw a brik like this in 2D using `Sprite.graphics`.

Comment: This would be my last choice i guess